# How to set ListViewItem's default image if image key could not be found

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a built in way to use a default image when the ListViewItem's ImageKey could not be found?

I have an ImageList:

- car.png
- house.png
- default.png

And a ListViewItem

```
var item = new ListViewItem("Item1");
item.ImageKey = "computer.png";
```

By default the ListView does not display an image in this case. Is there a possibility to display "default.png"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it (though there may be a more elegant way). You will likely need to adapt this to suit how you are populating your ListView. The basic code is like this:

```
string imageKey = "DefaultKey";
string someOtherKey = "SomeOtherKey";
if (lv.SmallImageList.Images.ContainsKey("SomeOtherKey"))
{
    imageKey = someOtherKey;
}
var item = new ListViewItem("Item1");
item.ImageKey = imageKey;
```

Note that, depending on how you are populating your list, this might be better pulled out into a function which returns the appropriate key:

```
string getImageKey(string candidateKey)
{
    if (lvAzureDirectory.SmallImageList.Images.ContainsKey(candidateKey))
    {
        return candidateKey;
    }
    else
    {
        return "DefaultKey";
    }
}
```

Comment: Although it is not an answer I expected to get, it is the way I would do it.